# What is the appropriate way to have as a data type for a dropdown list that has values in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a program where in I have a dropdown list that has a value of Item Conditions such as "New", "Used", "Acceptible". I am thinking of whether using VARCHAR or ENUM to be used as a datatype for this to be selected in the database. My question is, what is the appropriate data type for a dropdown list that has values that will communicate in the table values in database, VARCHAR or ENUM?

Answer (score 1):

for this case - always use integer as searching on integer data type is a lot faster. for example is if you would retrieve all records that are categorized as "Used". Since you are using mysql, use the tinyint data type.

I've been seeing a lot of write-ups that are against the usage of enum data type as it has a lot of drawbacks if not used properly.

varchar on the other hand is a lot slower than integer (indexed and unindexed).

Comment: Thank you for the response and tip, @kapitan